# Pattern matching in unix shell script

Tags: shell, unix

I have two files like below:

**File 1:**

```
id1
hftujdbbd
bdurijtbr
grhjend
Ghent
id2
fu Rubens
hejdnnd
bdudndn
id3
gjbfbd
vhrjend
rjndnd 
.
.
.
```

**File 2:**

```
id1
id2
```

I need to find the ids in file1 that are matching with ids in file2 and print all the lines related to that matched id. Please let me know how to implement this.

So the expected output is as below:

```
hftujdbbd
bdurijtbr
grhjend
Ghent
fu Rubens
hejdnnd
bdudndn
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages.  Normally, we expect people to show their best effort as part of the question, explaining where they're running into problems.   It's also sensible to show the expected output from your sample data.

Comment: Start by looking at the `join` command.

Comment: Hi, I don’t want the ids that are in common, I want the rest of the lines that belong to the matched id. So not sure if Join will do that.

Answer (score 0):

Using awk:

```
awk -F "/" 'NR==FNR { indx[$0]=1;next } indx[$2]==1 && ($1 == 2 || $1 == 3) { print }' file2 file1
```

Explanation:

```
awk -F "/" 'NR==FNR {                                        # Set the field separator to "/" and then process the first file (file2) (NR==FNR) 
                      indx[$0]=1;                            # Set the index of an array (indx) to the line
                      next 
                    } 
            indx[$2]==1 && ($1 == 2 || $1 == 3) {            # When processing the second file (file1), if there in an entry for the second "/" delimited field in index and the first field is 2 or 3, print the line
                      print 
                     }' file2 file1
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this and it’s not giving any output even if there are matching id’s.

Comment: Ykur expected output makes no sense? You have id1 and id2 in file2 and so why are they not in the expected output?

Comment: It coukd be that you just need to change && to ||

Answer (score 0):

Taking file1 and file2 as above

```
while read id; do
    if grep -w $id file1.txt > /dev/null 2>&1; then
        awk "/$id/{flag=1; next} /id[0-9]?/{flag=0} flag" file1.txt
    fi
done<file2.txt
```

output:

```
abhishekphukan$ bash script.sh 
hftujdbbd
bdurijtbr
grhjend
Ghent
fu Rubens
hejdnnd
bdudndn
```

Comment: I don’t want the list of ids that are present in file1 , I want the other records for that matching id.

Comment: Don't do `grep ...; if [ $? -eq 0 ];` It is much cleaner to write that as `if grep ...`